# What value to provide for the Kafka schema.registry.ssl.engine.factory.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, embedded-kafka

I have a spring boot application with some kafka providers/consumers and some integration tests(using embedded kafka) for them. Everything worked fine, until i have lifted the spring boot version to 2.3(from 2.1.x) and the spring-kafka to 2.6.0.

Now i am getting the following exception : `io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value  for configuration schema.registry.ssl.engine.factory.class: Class  could not be found.`

The error appears in trying to construct a consumer. I am using a custom `KafkaAvroDeserializer` with a `MockSchemaRegistryClient` which complains about the above property.

Is there a property that has to be set or has someone run into this issue before and has a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the version of the `kafka-avro-serializer` library to 5.5.0.